polars dataframe: columns of lists[some datatypes] to columns of (some datatypes)
have a polars dataframe. I wa doing some manipulations after which the column values are lists of some data types such as list of str or list of int. I want to those columns to be str or int. those lists only have one value in it so it should be easy right? How should I do it
Is this the best way to do it?
import polars as pl

# Sample DataFrame with multiple columns
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "col1": [[1], [2], [3]],  # list of int
    "col2": [["a"], ["b"], ["c"]],  # list of str
    "col3": [[4], [5], [6]]  # another list of int
})

# List of columns to convert
columns_to_convert = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]

# Apply the transformation to multiple columns
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col(col).list.first().alias(col) for col in columns_to_convert
)

print(df)

Output:
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ str  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ a    ┆ 4    │
│ 2    ┆ b    ┆ 5    │
│ 3    ┆ c    ┆ 6    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘

Is this compatible with lazyframe?

If the lists are all the same size (one element), the easiest option is to use explode, which can take a list of columns as an input (see documentation):
import polars as pl

df = pl.LazyFrame({
    "col1": [[1], [2], [3]],  # list of int
    "col2": [["a"], ["b"], ["c"]],  # list of str
    "col3": [[4], [5], [6]]  # another list of int
})

# List of columns to convert
columns_to_convert = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]

print(df.explode(columns_to_convert).collect())

which results to:
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ str  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ a    ┆ 4    │
│ 2    ┆ b    ┆ 5    │
│ 3    ┆ c    ┆ 6    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘

